# Magento 1: Display three products per row in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

how to display three products per row in Magento, after a certain count the products are repeating itself. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below step to do with per row products :

Goto `app/design/frontend/<your_package><your_theme>/layout/catalog.xml.`

Find the handle `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered`.

Put this line inside the block `product_list_toolbar` at very bottom

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><count>3</count></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento by default provides us a very good template for displaying different pages. It also provides a variety of layout files to display different pages with different layouts. But for our convenience, we need to do some modifications in the default layout of Magento.

One of the most common issue for product display is how to show 4 products instead of 3 in a row in Magento. Because Magento does not provide any functionality to change it from the admin side, we need to make it possible from our side i.e., by coding. We can easily change it by the help of an XML file.

**Step:1** Open your XML file from this path `app/design/frontend/default/YOUR_THEME/layout/catalog.xml`

**Step:2** In that file find out the code like this

```
<action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
```

**Step:3** Add this line below it

```
<action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
```

The above code will change the product count to 3.

You can use this code for `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_layered` to change the row count.

Hope it helps!!!